# What's the best option to connect from a foreign country to my work's VPN server in the USA?

Tags: windows-7, vpn, cisco-vpn-client

I want to connect from a foreign country to the VPN server at my workplace in the USA. I have two options:

1. Take my work computer to the foreign country and use it to connect to the VPN server in the USA.
2. Keep my work computer in the USA at my workplace and use my laptop in the foreign country to [RDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) to my work computer.

Which option is better and why? I have to access our intranet, [Subversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion)/[CVS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System) and other servers. What connection information (such as IP address, country I connected from, etc.) is logged by the VPN server?

I am using the Cisco VPN Client on Windows 7 on both the laptop and work computer.

Answer (score 5):

straight-shot VPN would be more secure, it is one single connection that is far more secure than an RDP session. Also, using the RDP session just to VPN to somewhere else creates two legs that will just make the connection that much more latent.